# Addon not updating when pressing F8

Tags: python, add-on, customization

I have a simple operator that prints out the string "Testing operator". I change the string to "Testing updated file", then go to Blender and press F8 to reload the script. I run the operator, but I still get "Testing operator", and not the updated string.

I have the script in a separate folder (not in the Blender script path), and have installed the addon through Blender's "Install from file". The script is only one file, and I'm editing it in Notepad++.

When I try to reinstall the addon, the update takes place. However, restarting Blender does nothing.

My question is thus: how can I make the refresh function work?

Note: The reason I don't have the script in Blender's script path, is that the script can easily be deleted by accident.

Code if necessary:

```
bl_info = {
    "name" : "Import addon",
    "author" : "Naioai Studios",
    "version" : (1, 0, 0),
    "blender" : (2, 7, 2),
    "location" : "View 3D > Edit Mode > Tool Shelf",
    "description" :
        "Allows for semi-automatic shipping",
    "warning" : "",
    "wiki_url" : "",
    "tracker_url" : "",
    "category" : "1_Custom",
    'support': 'COMMUNITY'
}

import bpy

def main():
    print("Testing updated flflflflf")

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Import addon for stickmen models"""
    bl_idname = "object.import_stickman"
    bl_label = "Import stickman"

    def execute(self, context):
        main()
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    #test call
    bpy.ops.object.import_stickman()
```

Comment: once you install the addon blender will take a copy of the file and save somewhere else and wont refer to the original file (it will be reading from the copy ) that's why reinstalling solve the problem but refreshing wont

Comment: What then, can be done to make the refresh function work?

Comment: Is there for instance a way of forcing Blender to refer to original file, or force Blender to copy every time it refreshes?

Comment: edit the copy that blender is using (in your  addon details you will see      file : destination )

Comment: why not execute and test the script (only the main) until you get the final script then finish by making the addon

Comment: does that work for you ?

Comment: To the last question @Chebhou: How does that work? Can this be done outside of Blender (Read: not using the text editor in Blender)?

Comment: see this [DOC guide on doing this](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_8/info_tips_and_tricks.html#executing-external-scripts) it shows how to execute a script file from outside blender

Comment: Any chance [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26982/935) helps?